# Immediately delete records inserted through SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlbulkcopy

In a specific business case flow, I need to immediately delete records inserted through `SqlBulkCopy`. The code works fine most of the time but I am seeing, sometimes the delete procedure does not find those records and data does not get deleted. Is it possible that the `WriteToServer` method returns control execution to next line, without completing the insert of the records?

This is my code:

```
// Insert
using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(strConnectionString))
{
   bulkCopy.BatchSize = 5000;
   bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = tableName;
   bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataTable)
}

// Few business case conditions
// Delete - Get Ids and pass as table param to the proc
using (var context = _dataContextFactory.CreateContext())
{
    var tableParam = new SqlParameter
            {
                  ParameterName = "@Ids",
                  Value = data,
             };
    context.ExecuteSqlCommand("[uspDeleteData]",tableParam);
}
```

If this is the case, can someone please suggest, how can I immediately delete these records.

Comment: "sometimes delete proc does not find those records and data does not get deleted" => this is a strange statement that requires more investigation. Can you reproduce the issue? Does it happen consistently with a specific data set? Are you profiling the database to diagnose the issue?

Comment: If you would delete, then why would you even write in the first place. You could instead write to a temp table or use transaction and roll back. Writing and immediately deleting doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Add your proc code.

Comment: I have a UI which insert in a "Request" table to insert/Delete the data so in a specific flow, user add the entry to insert data and then next entry to delete data. My code is reading this Request table and accordingly performing operations So Delete code is not immediately after insert code  but gets executed within few milliseconds.I am not able to reproduce this behavior all the time. As I mentioned, it works most of the time, but sometimes, data does not get deleted

Comment: And that doesn't answer the question why would you insert data that you would immediately delete. You could filter out the deleted data before SqlBulkCopy.Write. Anyway, SqlBulkCopy writes all the data you sent provided there aren't any conflicts. You should also consider SqlBulkCopying to a temp table instead (copy the Ids of deleted ones to another table and then do an insert server side checking temp and Ids tables).

Comment: But ***why*** are you first bulk-inserting records, only to deleted them again immediately after the insert?? Couldn't you just check for these conditions, and if the conditions are met, just **NOT insert** those rows??